# "Expired certificates" issue solved for browsers but not for command line tools

Tags: terminal, command-line, security, keychain

Today a strange phenomenon has started appearing on my Mojave mac.
In my browsers I started having trouble connecting to many websites, with a "expired certficate" warning. I solved that by putting a "Let's Encrypt certificate" in the KeyChain Access app as explained at https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/os-x-10-11-clients-not-connecting-to-site-with-lets-encrypt-certificates/161576/11.

The problem was then solved for my browsers, but it persisted for the Terminal app (which is surprising because the command-line interface is more "low-level" and therefore usually more robust ans stable than web browsers).

Thus, while all of my browsers can access  https://letsencrypt.org without any problem, in the terminal I get :

> $ wget https://letsencrypt.org
> --2022-10-28 17:24:27--  https://letsencrypt.org/ Resolving letsencrypt.org (letsencrypt.org)... 34.159.75.132, 34.159.58.69
> Connecting to letsencrypt.org (letsencrypt.org)|34.159.75.132|:443...
> connected. ERROR: cannot verify letsencrypt.org's certificate, issued
> by ‘CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:   Issued certificate has expired. To
> connect to letsencrypt.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'

Here I could simply add `--no-check-certificate` as indicated in the error message, but that's not doable for complex tools using hundreds of calls to `wget`, `curl` or similar commands.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122613/24330

Comment: @AllInOne Not, it doesn't answer my question: 1) It only deals with curl and not other commands, such as wget 2) I applied all the ideas suggested in those answers and still curl doesn't work.